# How to recognize object when in a string with query() in Python for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to pull the first row from each listed year in my dataframe. Here is an example of what it looks like:[image: Example Data]

So, I want the first 2008, 2004, 2000, etc. row all pulled into one dataframe.

```
index = []
for year in usa.Edition:
    index.append(usa.query("Edition == year").head(1))
    
print(index)
```

I figured a for loop would be great for this, and found the `query` function to find which rows I need, to append them to my `index` object that I can later print as my final result. However, I think b/c `year` has to be in quotes, it is unable to pick it up. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: A for loop is almost never the answer when it comes to pandas. `df.groupby('Edition').head(1)` may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To address the part of your question that asks how to access `year` in `query()`: you can use `@year` to access python variables. See [`query()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) docs which state:

> You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character like @a + b.

Separately, to get the first row (as currently ordered, which seems to be by `Total`) in each `Edition`, you can do this:

```py
df = usa.groupby('Edition').first().reset_index().sort_values('Edition', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Explanation:

- use `groupby()` to get groups of like value of `Edition` and use `first()` to take the first row in each group (which seems to be the highest by `Total`)
- use `reset_index()` to make `Edition` a column again (since `groupby()` moved it into the index)
- use `sort_values()` to order the results by descending value of `Edition`, and use `reset_index()` to replace the old index with one that is ascending from 0 by increments of 1.

---

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
usa = pd.DataFrame({
'Medal':range(9),
'Edition':[2008,2008,2008,2004,2004,2004,2000,2000,2000], 'Athlete':['PHELPS','COUGHLIN','LIUKIN','JONES','SMITH','WARREN','HOYT','JAMISON','LANE'],
'Bronze':[0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2],
'Gold':  [3,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1],
'Silver':[2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,0],
'Total': [5,4,3,6,9,12,9,6,3]})
print(usa)

df = usa.groupby('Edition').first().reset_index().sort_values('Edition', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Input:

```
   Medal  Edition   Athlete  Bronze  Gold  Silver  Total
0      0     2008    PHELPS       0     3       2      5
1      1     2008  COUGHLIN       1     0       3      4
2      2     2008    LIUKIN       2     1       0      3
3      3     2004     JONES       3     2       1      6
4      4     2004     SMITH       4     3       2      9
5      5     2004    WARREN       5     4       3     12
6      6     2000      HOYT       0     5       4      9
7      7     2000   JAMISON       1     0       5      6
8      8     2000      LANE       2     1       0      3
```

Output:

```
   Edition  Medal Athlete  Bronze  Gold  Silver  Total
2     2008      0  PHELPS       0     3       2      5
1     2004      3   JONES       3     2       1      6
0     2000      6    HOYT       0     5       4      9
```

Comment: @shrey_shankar Do you need additional help with your question?

Comment: @shrey_shankar If you don't need any more help, please consider marking this answer as "accepted" assuming it addressed your question.

Comment: the other comment solved my question with a simpler solution so I'm counting that as the answer